# how does amcl updates turtlebot's current location to move_base

Tags: navigation, turtlebot, ros-hydro, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I was reading up on ROS's navigation stack as well as amcl 's documentation when I realized from the stack's diagram
that move_base does not subscribe to /amcl_pose , which amcl uses to publish the robot's estimated pose in the map. In that case how does move_base update the current localized pose of the robot ?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/168491/how-does-amcl-updates-turtlebot%27s-current-location-to-move_base/) by [zenifed](https://answers.ros.org/users/5788/zenifed/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2014-05-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Everything is send via TF. AMCL usually provides the /map -> /odom transform.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-05-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zenifed](https://answers.ros.org/users/5788/zenifed/) on 2014-05-25**:
Correct me if I am wrong, so the robot's current position is maintained via a odom transform from the robot's initial position? Also with the AMCL active, the robot no longer subscribe to /tf from the sensor and odometry source?